# Gigabyte GA-F2A88XN No onboard video

Tags: video, motherboard, on-board-peripheral

So I've been struggling with this motherboard for like a 3 straight days, and finally figured out the problem is the on board video out would not allow me to post. Well it was posting, I just couldn't see it was posting. My objective is the only use 1 of the onboard HDMI plug as the only and primary output to my TV.

The only way I can see anything on the screen is to install a random PCI-Express video card to get any picture on the screen.

After I finally got into BIOS. I went to Peripherals > GFX Configuration >

And there is 2 Options and a few suboptions

A. **Primary Video Device** -> A1. IGD Video -> A2. NB PCIe Slot Video (default)

B. **Integrated Graphics** -> B1. Auto (default) -> B2. Disabled -> B3. Force

According to the Manual it says:

```
(Primary)
```

**IGD Video:** Sets the onboard Graphics as the first display

**NB PCIe Slot Video:** Sets the PCI Express graphics card on the PCI Express Slot controlled by the North Bridge as the first display (default)

> (Integrated Graphics)

Enable or disables the onboard graphics function

**Auto:** The BIOS will automatically enable or disable the on-board graphics depending on the graphics card being installed. (Default)

**Disabled:** Disables on-board graphics.

**Force:** Always activates the on-board graphics, whether or not the PCI Express card is installed. *IF force -> UMA Frame Buffer Size* -> Auto (default), 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G

Based on the Default values, if there is no video card installed, there should be a signal from any of the Display ports on the motherboard, But I get nothing.

I've tried options > IGD  Video and Force, and still get nothing. Even with these options according to the manual, if i place a video card in the pci express slot, it should not work. But it does. I don't understand what is going on here.

Motherboard: [GA-F2A88XN](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4745#ov)

CPU: Athlon X4 760K

Comment: You mention that the system "was posting, I just couldn't see it"... how do you know this?
You may be correct, which means that the TV won't support low resolutions (such as the POST screen).
You really should install the OS using a computer monitor via DVI then connect it to the TV via HDMI after the video drivers are installed (whilst still connected to the monitor via DVI) so you can set the correct HDMI settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be while your board supports an igpu but your processor dosen't have one. You mentioned a Athlon X4 760K (on chat) - which by all accounts, dosen't have a IGPU. You'd want an A series processor for that.

Answer (score 2):

according to the system specs for that mainboard (http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4745#sp) you need to have a CPU with built-in graphics - exactly as Journeyman suggested.

Can you tell me what CPU you are using with this mainboard?  [Here is the CPU compatibility list](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4745#) (http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4745#)... Any CPU listed on there that has **N/A** for the GPU Frequency means it does not have a built-in graphics processing and will require an add-on graphics card for use.

Can you also use the DVI out on the mainboard to connect the monitor without the PCIe graphics card installed and confirm that you DON'T get POST while using DVI.
It may be that the HDMI output for the mainboard is OS specific and won't function until the OS "enables" it during boot-up.